# Can the HALT CPU instruction be used to stop attacks?

Tags: antivirus

Not sure what the HALT CPU instruction is used for these days but I was thinking that if there was a kind of watchdog process that could determine if a computer had gotten infected and stop it right away, that would reduce the damage.

Would halting the CPU be a useful way to prevent serious infections or other system compromises?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting idea, but that instruction doesn't do what you think it does. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLT_(x86_instruction)):

> In the x86 computer architecture, `HLT` (halt) is an assembly language instruction which halts the central processing unit (CPU) until the next external interrupt is fired. Interrupts are signals sent by hardware devices to the CPU alerting it that an event occurred to which it should react.

A kernel-mode driver could issue that instruction, but the next hardware interrupt would have the CPU resume whatever it was doing. Also [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt):

> For example, pressing a key on the keyboard or moving the mouse triggers hardware interrupts that cause the processor to read the keystroke or mouse position.

The instruction's real purpose is to save power, since stopping the CPU saves a lot of power compared to a no-op loop. I'm sure your computer uses `HLT` many times a day without you noticing.

If the system needs to halt immediately, a more effective option would be to trigger a bugcheck (a fatal system crash, like a BSOD on Windows). Another option is to scribble over fault handlers to get a [triple fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_fault), which can cause the machine to reboot.

Comment: And with multicores, it's even less helpful...

Comment: OK. I guess a sentence or two about what a bugcheck is would be helpful, I have never heard of that. I thought that the Halt was an irreversible stop and the CPU could only restart with a power-up, which would give a chance to pre-check the OS before re-loading it. Perhaps there should be an instruction to do that? Maybe a bus lock and then a halt? Could malicious software trigger a hardware interrupt if the CPU was halted? I was just trying to find a way to stop the infection or wrong use from going forward. Maybe the system could cause a power-down instead?

Comment: @nocomprende A bugcheck is a fatal system crash, like a BSOD on Windows or a kernel panic on Linux. Malicious software couldn't create an interrupt, but you would almost certainly get an interrupt from some device fairly soon. I've also added a note about triple faults, which cause an immediate power cycle.

Comment: So, throw three faults and make it power cycle, but have it stay offline or in safe mode or something. I guess my knowledge is obsolete. Thank you.

Comment: A triple fault does not cause a power cycle, it causes a CPU reset. Subtle difference that may be relevant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_fault#Other_uses // cc @nocomprende

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Hmm, it does seem that the triple fault response varies from system to system - that same article says in the summary: "This typically causes the motherboard hardware to initiate a CPU reset which in turn causes the whole computer to reboot."

Comment: @BenN Reboot yes, power cycle no. (Though you can set things up such that the triple fault does not reboot the system.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks, I've slightly adjusted my answer.